# Calling stored procedure error on return value error data type nvarchar(max) to int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I calling a `stored procedure` and it has an `int` return value. However there is an error on returning the value back to my back end.

```
public async Task<string> CreatePortfolio(Portfolio portfolio)
{
    string statusMessage;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection))
    {
        SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter(); //Holds the bit that determines if insert was successful or not

        SqlCommand command;
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "USP_Add_Portfolio";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@portfolioName", portfolio.PortfolioName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", portfolio.Description);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createID", portfolio.CreateID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateID", portfolio.UpdateID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

        int i = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if(i == 1)
        {
            statusMessage = command.Parameters["@statusMessage"].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            statusMessage = "Error while adding please contact your administrator";
        }
    }
    return statusMessage;
}
```

This is the `stored procedure`:

```sql
create procedure USP_Add_Portfolio
    (@portfolioName as nchar(30) = null,
     @description as nvarchar(200) = null,
     @createID as nvarchar(40) = null,
     @updateID as nvarchar(40) = null,
     @statusMessage as nvarchar(max) output)
as
    declare @success as int = 0

    if @portfolioName is null
        raiserror('Stored procedure USP_Add_Portfolio - Missing Parameter @portfolioName', 16,1)
    else if exists( select * from Portfolio where [Portfolio_Name] = @portfolioName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
    begin
        set @statusMessage = rtrim(@portfolioName) + ' already exists please try another portfolio name'
        raiserror('Stored procedure USP_Add_Portfolio - Already exists @portfolioName', 16,1)
        return 0
    end
    else if @createID is null
        raiserror('Stored procedure USP_Add_Portfolio - Missing Parameter @Create_ID', 16,1)
    else if @updateID is null
        raiserror('Stored procedure USP_Add_Portfolio - Missing Parameter @Update_ID', 16,1)
    else
        begin
            insert into Portfolio ([Portfolio_Name], [Long_Description], [Create_ID], [Create_TS], [Update_ID], [Update_TS])
            values (@portfolioName, @description, @createID, getdate(), @updateID, getdate())
            --Check to see if insert worked
            set @statusMessage = case when @@ROWCOUNT = 1 then 'Successfully added ' + @portfolioName else 'Unable to add please try again' end
            set @success = case when @@ROWCOUNT = 1 then 1 else 0 end
        end
        return @success
go
```

The stored procedure finishes and it adds the new record but it errors on

```
int i = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Error:

> expecting an int but gets nvarchar

Comment: You do realise that you are testing the number of rows modified with your line `if (i = 1)` not the return result from your proc? (Which would be `returnValue.Value`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look correct because `SqlDbType.NVarChar` is an enumeration value:

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

What happens if you use this instead:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@statusMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: @DaleBurrell You are incorrect. I checked my answer before responding, as best as possible given the lack of example data, table schema, etc.. OP's question is flawed. When using OP's code there is an exception. When using my code there is no exception.

Comment: Good call. I can highly recommend never using `SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue` as it hides too much and doesn't allow precision - which should always be included for performance.

Comment: @DaleBurrell No problem. Would be great if question askers posted enough code to be able to replicate their issue.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry for not putting up enough information. I will remember for next time. I appreciate the help your solution works. Can I ask why we use -1 for the size? is it because I set an nvarchar(max)? If I specify the size then I can change the -1 to the appropriate size value?

Comment: @HenryACN In SQL Server you can declare up to `char(8000)`, `varchar(8000)`, `nchar(4000)` or `nvarchar(4000)` to stay within a single database page. If you try to define larger values it will error. The `(max)` versions are a bit special in that they have length specifiers of `-1` in `sys.types` and are kept in LOB Storage (along with types like `blob`, `text` and `xml`) outside of the normal pages that the rest of your table and index data use. Using `-1` on the client side indicates that these are `(max)` types as opposed to any other length less than or equal to 8000 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery` (not worrying about the async for the moment...) returns the number of rows affected for UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, and -1 otherwise.  It does NOT return information directly from the stored procedure.

In your case above, I think you should call the "await" without the "int i =" and not worry about the return value from the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` call. Instead, after the value, look at the value in `returnValue.Value`, which would be the value of the "return" parameter. It is an object, so verify the type or use `Convert.ToInt32()`.